# How can I make my footer stick to the bottom of the page?

Tags: css, sticky-footer

[Problem area](http://antonpug.com/comingsoon)

As you can see in the website above, the footer is not attached to the bottom of the page because there's not enough content. I would like the footer:

- to be at the bottom of the page when there's no scrolling
- when the window is further downsized, I want my content to define the minimum (in other words, the footer should never overlap the content
- when there's a lot of content, I want the footer to be at the bottom of the page (not necessarily visible until scrolled)

I tried using the example on http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/, with little success, the best I have been able to get to is something that kind of sticks the footer to the bottom, but it overlaps the content when the window is resized.

Can anyone tell me if there's a way to get it to work without changing the page structure?

I have already spent about 6 hours trying to get this to work and tried countless techniques. I would really appreciate if someone could try doing it and only submit an answer that they tested against my site. Like I said, I would like to do this without having to change the structure of the code.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this:-

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 155px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

<sup>[Credits for above code](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)</sup>

Also check references:-

- [A CSS Sticky Footer that just works](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)
- [how to use this sticky footer code.](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)

Comment: `position: fixed;`? This is not the way sticky footer works, zoom in and scroll the content, you will realize what I was saying

Comment: So using this method (Fait's Method), I am able to get to the same point as I am with the cssstickyfooter.com method (which doesn't need a push), however either way, unless I change page (same thing as wrapper on your example) to wrapper, there is no minimum height on the page and resizing the window makes the footer cover content :/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `min-height` to `page`

```
 #page
 {
   min-height:210px;
 }
```